# How to change the font "Font Awesome" (with the SVG method) when the menu is open?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, font-awesome

I created a main menu with font "Font Awesome".

I want the collapse menu to display a "plus" when closed and a "minus" when open.

If I use the method "Web Fonts with CSS", it works with the CSS below.

But if I use the "SVG with JavaScript" method, it does not work.

How to correctly display the font with the methide SVG ?

Here is the page concerned, it is in the menu on the left :

https://www.s1biose.com/groupe/recettes-et-astuces

Here is the CSS and HTML code of my menu:

```css
#block-menuprincipal li.dropdown > a:before {
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        content: "\f055";
        font-weight: 900;
        font-size: 1.33333em;
        line-height: .75em;
        vertical-align: -.0667em;
        display: inline-block;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-rendering: auto;
    }
    
    #block-menuprincipal li.dropdown > a[aria-expanded=true]:before {
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        content: "\f056";
        font-weight: 900;
        font-size: 1.33333em;
        line-height: .75em;
        vertical-align: -.0667em;
        display: inline-block;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-rendering: auto;
    }
```

```html
<nav role="navigation" aria-labelledby="block-navigationprincipale-menu" id="block-navigationprincipale">
           <ul class="menu nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="expanded dropdown open">
                 <a href="/boutique" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Stores</a>
                    <ul class="menu dropdown-menu">
                       <li>
                          <a href="/boutique" data-drupal-link-system-path="boutique"><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Stores</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                          <a href="/produit" data-drupal-link-system-path="produit"><i class="fas fa-gift fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Products</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                          <a href="/service" data-drupal-link-system-path="service"><i class="fas fa-sign-language fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Services</a>
                       </li>
                    </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="expanded dropdown">
                 <a href="/groupe" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Groups</a>
                    <ul class="menu dropdown-menu">
                       <li>
                          <a href="/groupe" data-drupal-link-system-path="groupe"><i class="fas fa-users fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Groups</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                          <a href="/annonce" data-drupal-link-system-path="annonce"><i class="fas fa-newspaper fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Ads</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                          <a href="/article" data-drupal-link-system-path="article"><i class="fas fa-file-alt fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Articles</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                          <a href="/discussion" data-drupal-link-system-path="discussion"><i class="fas fa-comments fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Discussions</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                          <a href="/recette" data-drupal-link-system-path="recette"><i class="fas fa-utensils fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Recipes</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                          <a href="/itineraire" data-drupal-link-system-path="itineraire"><i class="fas fa-map-signs fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Itineraries</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                          <a href="/evenement" data-drupal-link-system-path="evenement"><i class="fas fa-calendar fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Events</a>
                       </li>
                    </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                 <a href="/profil" data-drupal-link-system-path="profil"><i class="fas fa-id-card fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Profiles</a>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </nav>
```

> Web Fonts with CSS

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUZkA.png)

> SVG with JavaScript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uueaz.png)

Comment: So you are asking it again....

Comment: @epascarello I deleted the other question and improved it. The link in the comment did not answer the problem

Comment: @epascarello Why did you put -1 ?

Comment: It was not me, would you like another one?

Comment: @epascarello +1 otherwise the question will not be seen and I should post it again

Comment: read both answers of the duplicate question

Comment: @TemaniAfif great, thank you

Comment: @TemaniAfif This method can not be used in production. The performances are a disaster.

Comment: so you have to consider somethin else :) i have provided you with a fix to the issue .. in this case you can consider using CSS method not JS